# Inserting multiple new rows to UITableView fails after 3 times

Tags: swift, api, uitableview, pagination, insert

I read Apple's documentation and many other people's questions in here but still can't fully understand the structure of **how to insert multiple rows** to the `UITableView` using the `insertRows(at:with:)`.

Can someone please explain in simple English how to do so?

I am using an `API` to fetch articles. I use `pagination`. Every time I fetch a new "batch" of articles I want to add them at the bottom of the UITableView.

When I run my code - it works 3 times and then I get an error and I can't figure out why -.-

This is my function and my attempt of adding the rows:

```
func fetchNewsFromAPI(searchWords: String = "news", pageSizeToFetch: PageSizeForFetching, completionHandler: @escaping (String?, Int?) -> ()) {
    repository.fetchNewsFromAPI(searchWords: searchWords, pageSizeType: pageSizeToFetch, savedArticles: savedArticles, currentPage: currentPaginationPage) {
        articles, totalPages, statusMsg in
        if let statusMsg = statusMsg {
            self.newsArray = []
            completionHandler(statusMsg, nil)
        } else {
            print("TOTAL RESULTS: \(totalPages!)")
            self.currentPaginationPage += 1
            if let totalPages = totalPages {
                self.totalPaginationPages = totalPages
            }
            self.newsArray.append(contentsOf: articles!)
            completionHandler(nil, articles?.count)
        }
    }
}



        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let position = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    if position > (searchResultsTableView.contentSize.height - 100 - scrollView.frame.size.height) && !isPaginating {
        isPaginating = true
        viewModel.fetchNewsFromAPI(searchWords: searchTextField.text!, pageSizeToFetch: .articlesList) { error, numArticlesFetched in
            if error == nil {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.searchResultsDataSource.models = self.viewModel.newsArray
                    
                    print("JUST FETCHED \(numArticlesFetched!) ARTICLES")
                    if numArticlesFetched != 0 {
                        self.searchResultsTableView.beginUpdates()
                        var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
                        let rangeStart = numArticlesFetched!
                         let rangeEnd = rangeStart + (numArticlesFetched! - 1)
                         for i in rangeStart...rangeEnd {
                             indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
                         }
                        self.searchResultsTableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.right)
                        self.searchResultsTableView.endUpdates()
                    }
                    
                    self.searchResultsTableView.tableFooterView = nil
                }
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }
            self.isPaginating = false
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
Thread 1: "attempt to insert row 7 into section 0, but there are only 7 rows in section 0 after the update"
```

Comment: You use `self.searchResultsDataSource.models` or `self.viewModel.newsArray` in cellForRowAt, numberOfItemsInsection, numberOfSection?

Comment: I have a file with generic code for TableViews - `TableViewDataSourceManager<Model>` with `var models: [Model]` in it.
All my table functions are inside it and are depending on the models variable.
When I set up this current TableView: 

`self.searchResultsDataSource = TableViewDataSourceManager(
            models: viewModel.newsArray,
            reuseIdentifier: "cellIdentifier"
        ) {
// define cell in here
}
searchResultsTableView.dataSource = searchResultsDataSource
searchResultsTableView.delegate = self`

Does this answer your question? @Larme

Comment: Do you get same number of items every time when you call the API? It seems the problem is in ```et rangeStart = numArticlesFetched!``` and ```let rangeEnd = rangeStart + (numArticlesFetched! - 1)```. Please check the calculation of row.

Comment: I always try to fetch 7 items from the API.
When writing my comment I was fetching data on a keyword that had 1400+ results of articles, so no way that after getting 7 articles for 3 times suddenly I get less than 7 articles and therefore the app crushes @talha_kuet

Comment: That means the value of ```numArticlesFetched```  is always 7 for first 3 times or it's value is like 7, 14, 21..... @NoamKurtzer

Comment: It's 7 every time because I always call for just 7 articles from the api @talha_kuet

Comment: The problem may be in ```let rangeStart = numArticlesFetched!``` ```let rangeEnd = rangeStart + (numArticlesFetched! - 1)``` lines. Because every time the ```rangeStart``` value is 7 and ```rangeEnd``` value is 13. And also the dataSource may not be updated.

Comment: Changed my code to:
`var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
                            let originalLastIndex = self.viewModel.newsArray.count - 1 - numArticlesFetched!
                            let newLastIndex = self.viewModel.newsArray.count - 1
                            for i in originalLastIndex...(newLastIndex - 1) {
                                indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0))
                            }
                            self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableView.RowAnimation.none)`


Now it works 7 times then crashes @talha_kuet

Comment: Change ```for i in originalLastIndex...(newLastIndex - 1) { indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) }``` to ```for i in originalLastIndex...newLastIndex { indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)) }``` and check if it works or not.

Comment: It makes it break down right on the first paginating with the error: `Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (14) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (7), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (8 inserted, 0 deleted)` @talha_kuet

Comment: oh, my calculation was wrong. But i don't have any other idea why this issue is occurring.